# setTimeout in foreach elements not working

Tags: javascript

I want `translate` the all elements in my slider but want each element `translate` with a delay,i have this idea , this is my code :

```
 this.button_right.addEventListener( "click", function( e ) {

  e.preventDefault();
  self.items.forEach(function (element,index) {

   setTimeout(function(){
  element.style.transform = 'translate(-150px, 0)';
  },1000);

});

});
```

any body have better idea?

Comment: I've seen this question enough to know there is a duplicate somewhere.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Multiply `delay` with `index`

```js
this.button_right.addEventListener("click", function(e) {
  e.preventDefault();
  self.items.forEach(function(element, index) {
    setTimeout(function() {
      element.style.transform = 'translate(-150px, 0)';
    }, (1000 * (index + 1)));
  });
});
```

Comment: @rayon : Any specific reason of increasing the delay here ?

Comment: @NikhilMaheshwari, All the statements in `setTimeout` will get executed once..with the delay of `1000`..they are queued..

Comment: @NikhilMaheshwari, Without delay: https://jsfiddle.net/rayon_1990/4ywset95/ And with delay: https://jsfiddle.net/rayon_1990/4ywset95/1/